# Google Services OAuth requests returns HTTP 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0, file-get-contents

I'm trying to build a basic app where I can modify my own google calendar using Google's RESTful api, but I'm having trouble getting the oAuth token. I've chosen to do it using the Services Application oAuth flow - I don't want to have to constantly re-agree to letting my own app use my calendar, but if there's a better way to do this please let me know.

Every time I make the http request I get a Bad Request error. Any ideas/help?

Here's the code:

```
            <?php

            $payload = array(
                   "iss"=>"services client email",
                   "scope"=>"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
                   "aud"=>"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
                   "iat"=>date("U"),
                   "exp"=>date("U")+3600
                );

            $key = "Simple API key";
            $jwt = encode_header($payload,$key);

            print_r(request_g_token($jwt));


            function request_g_token($jwt)
            {
                $data = array(
                    'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
                    'assertion' => $jwt
                );

                $data = http_build_query($data);
                $url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
                //echo $data;
                $opts = array('http' =>
                    array(
                        'protocol_version' => '1.1',    
                        'method'  => 'POST',
                        'header' => "Host: accounts.google.com\r\n" .
                                    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                        'content' => $data
                    )
                );

                $context = stream_context_create($opts);

                return (file_get_contents($url, false, $context));
            }

            function urlsafeb64encode($input){
                return str_replace('=','',strtr(base64_encode($input),'+/','-_'));
            }

            function encode_header($payload, $key, $algo = 'RS256'){
                $header = array('typ' => 'JWT', 'alg' => $algo);

                $segments = array();
                $segments[] = urlsafeb64encode(json_encode($header));
                $segments[] = urlsafeb64encode(json_encode($payload));
                $signing_input = implode('.',$segments);

                $sig = sign_encode($signing_input,$key);
                $segments[]=urlsafeb64encode($sig);

                return implode('.',$segments);
            }

            function sign_encode($msg, $key){
                    return hash_hmac('sha256', $msg, $key, true);
            }
            ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**UPDATE**

So I went through the service process again and realized I need to use a private key, which I'm now doing. My major question is whether or not to include the "private-key.p12" part of what I downloaded from google or not. I'm still receiving a Bad Request error unfortunately...

**UPDATE 2**

Realized I needed to pull the key *from* the pk12 file, and I did so with this code:

```
    function getKey($file){
        $p12cert = array();

        $fd = fopen($file, 'r');
        $p12buf = fread($fd,filesize($file));
        fclose($fd);

        if ( openssl_pkcs12_read($p12buf, $p12cert, 'notasecret') )
        {
            //worked
            $temp = $p12cert['pkey'];
            $temp = str_replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----","",$temp);
            $temp = str_replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----","",$temp);
            return $temp;
        }
        else
        {
            //failed
            return "failed";
        }   
    }
```

However, it's still giving me a bad request error and I think it's to do with the fact that the key comes back in multiple lines. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing this issue, I've basically come to the conclusion that google hasn't interfaced calendar with their service accounts yet, and am using a refresh token to achieve similar results without having to log in all the time.